# how should I manage very large output with pexpect?

Tags: python-3.x, large-data, large-files, pexpect, large-data-volumes

I want to use pexpect to check file contents by inodes through debugfs.
The simple, obvious... and wrong way of doing that would be to expect the “debugfs:  ” prompt and then analyze the `.before` string. However, doing that will obviously cause a buffer or memory overflow for the very large files. Is there a "right" way to read (and process) my output block by block until I get the matching content ?

I have found the following way, but it's not very efficient:

```
import pexpect
cat=pexpect.spawn("debugfs -cD -R 'cat <123456>' /dev/md0", timeout=600)
patterns = ["debugfs:  ", "^.{"+str(2**20)+"}"]
while cat.expect(patterns)==1:
    print(len(cat.before), len(cat.after), len(cat.buffer))

print(len(cat.before), len(cat.after), len(cat.buffer))
```

Comment: since all you're doing is `cat` why don't you open the file and read it all by yourself?

Comment: Because the `cat /dev/md0` is just a test to see if it works. I'm not interested in the content of `/dev/md0`I'm interrested in the output of `debugfs` and the data I will be accessing will be refered to by inodes and not by filenames.

Comment: I adjusted the code

Comment: what are you going to do upon matching `debugfs: `? do you want to save all data before  the `debugfs: ` promtp?

Comment: compute `md5sum`

Comment: pexpect is for interactive commands. For non-interactive commands see python's [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: debugfs IS an interactive application ! In the example, I use it non-interactively for one inode, but in this case i could as well do it manually. In the real application, I'll have many inodes to check, and I would like to send commands to debugfs in order to avoid reloading it for each file. The general Idea, is have a loop on all used inodes, read their content, and pipe it to md5sum.